# getting too much memory allocation with no leaks, app crashes more likely on ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I have this code of getting two video frames each of two different video. I am merging them into single frame and then creating a movie with merged frames. But the problem is app crashes due to memory warning. Here is my code:

```
NSString *filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Documents/movie.mp4"]];
NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:outputURL];
float frame = 0.00;
int count = 10;  

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
docPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"OutPut"];
BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:docPath];

if (success) {
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:docPath error:nil];
}

[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:docPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

for (frame = (frameStartTime); frame < (frameStartTime+5); frame+=0.033) {
    UIImage * singleFrameImage = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:frame timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
    [player pause];
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"export2%d.png",count];
    NSString * file = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:imageName ofType:nil];
    UIImage *overlayImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file]];

    count = count + 1;
    NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docPath, imageName];
    if (overlayImage) {
        UIImage *  outImage = [self mergeImage:singleFrameImage withImage:overlayImage];
        NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(outImage)];
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:imagePath contents:imgData attributes:nil];
        [imgData release];
    }
    else {
        NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(singleFrameImage);
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:imagePath contents:imgData attributes:nil];               
    }
    [outputFramesArray addObject:imagePath];
}

[player release];

if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];    
}

NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Documents/movie1.mp4"]];
NSLog(@"filePath %@", path);

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
}

[self writeImageAsMovie:outputFramesArray toPath:path size:CGSizeMake(480, 320) duration:10];
NSLog(@"hello Your layering is completed");
[outputFramesArray removeAllObjects];
[outputFramesArray release];
```

The allocation in instrument is maximum in this line (90%):

```
NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(outImage)];
```

In my whole app, the allocation level rise at only this point of code reaches to 130MB.

Could any of you suggest any solution?

Comment: do not copy the returnvalue of `UIImagePNGRepresentation`, instead use  it directly `NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(outImage)`

Comment: sorry for that but I had actually read the title as **getting too much money allocation with no leaks**. I wish you are.

Comment: hi Jonathan , earlier I was doing the same but in instrument it was showing 90% memory allocations so I manually alloc init and release it.

Comment: @Skyler: hi there, I wish to have that with no leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most like because you are consuming memory within your loop and the allocated memory in the current stack gets too big before you return to the main loop where things get deallocated.

Read this [blog post](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/a-look-under-arcs-hood-episode-3/) for more details.

Do this:

```
...
for (frame = (frameStartTime); frame < (frameStartTime+5); frame+=0.033)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Do whatever you do in your for loop...
    }
}
...
```

It will create a local pool that gets drained at each iteration.

Comment: Ya @mprivat: you got it but sorry i dont mention that i had done that before but it does prooved to worthfull to me, thx for your reply